# adding logo in angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-bootstrap

> hi friends i am new to this mean stack application. I want to insert a
>   logo in my application i used the fallowing code in index.html file

```
    <html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.21" data-semver="1.2.21" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="smart-table.debug.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script><!-- ui router cdn -->
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="finance" class="container">
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="page-header">
            <div class="container">
                <img id="logo-main" src="../images/saf-logo.png" width="500" height="75" alt="Logo Thing main logo" class="image-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                </div>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                             <li><a ui-sref="add-client">Register Form</a></li>
                            <li><a ui-sref="client-view">Clients View</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a ui-sref="chart">Chart</a></li> -->
                        </ul>
                 </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
                <!-- THIS IS WHERE WE WILL INJECT OUR CONTENT ============================== -->
            <div ui-view> </div>
        </div>





</body>

</html>
```

> But it shows the fallowing error in console when i run the
>   application.  GET http://localhost:8000/images/saf-logo.png 404 (Not
>   Found)
>   I using the angularjs expressjs mongodb and node.js
>
> controler.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);
console.log("controller out side");
app.controller('finance',['$scope',function($scope){
    // console.log("inside controller");
}])
```

> express code.

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
console.log("welcome to finance app");
app.listen(8000);
```

> package.json file

```
{
  "name": "finance",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.10",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.10",
    "angular-aria": "^1.5.10",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.5",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "express": "^4.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "index":"nodemon src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough context here. Please post **all your relevant code** so people can help - express code, your project structure - e.g where is your logo, etc.

Comment: `src="../images/saf-logo.png"` will not work - in web apps, the src of an image can be relative to where the site is being served from (i.e. your base) so it's just as `src="../images/saf-logo.png"` - now the problem is probably related to how Express is configured to serve resources. so please post the express code

Comment: So then... is your image in the right folder - e.g. `public/images/saf-logo.png` ? public should be a folder inside your current-working-directory when you start node/express

Comment: yes its loading when running that particular html file but when i run through localhost:8000 it gives an 404 error

Comment: hmm, try moving the static part first in express then the bodyparser - e.g.  `var app=express();  app.use(express.static('public')); var bodyParser=require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: Still i am not getting that image in the browser

Comment: how do you start the server (e.g. using a script or directly with node, npm start ... )?

Comment: npm strat using app.listen(8000)

Comment: ok, so how is your package.json file, how is the start script defined?